# How can propagation time be greater than transmission time?

Tags: networking

Please help me out understanding a concept in computer networks. I have understood what propagation delay and transmission time means. I can't understand how propagation time can be greater than transmission time? Please explain with one such example.

Answer (score -1):

Transmission time = time it takes to send (dispatch) the data.

Propagation delay = time it takes for the data to reach the other side.
[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_time)

For example, suppose you're sending 10 bits of data from the North Pole to the South Pole. If, for example, your computer (which is very old) has a 1bit/ms bit rate for sending, the transmission time would be 10ms. However, due to the length and the great number of hops required between the north and south poles, it could take 30ms for the first bit (and assuming everything goes well, for the other bits as well) to reach the south pole.
Thus, propagation time > transmission time.